# Why does not my particle system collision work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, particle-system

I have added a particle system where I have checked the collider option and added a world particle collider. See the image below.

In the script that is attached to the particle system I have:

```
void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) {
    Debug.Log("Particle was hit!");
}
```

The bullets that are fired don´t seem to hit the particles since the above message is not printed. The bullets are spheres with a sphere collider and a rigidbody attached. The rigidbody is set to non-kinematic (the checkbox is not checked) if that matters.

Also, the bullet object has a script attached with the same lines as above:

```
void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) {
    Debug.Log("Bullet was hit!");
}
```

But it is not printed as well.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm experiencing the same using Unity 2017.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t remember if I ever solved it. I suggest you ask the question on the Unity discussion forums where the activity is high: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/

Answer (score 2):

Double check that you have this script attached to your particle system and not any arbitrary gameobject.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have "Is trigger" disabled on Sphere Collider, or you're particles too small and don't hit the actual collider.
Tried to simulate your situation, all works fine.